# Extract values from JSON array using XPath?

Tags: json, xpath, jsonpath

I'm pretty new to XPath... 
I need to extract only the values ***2124,143*** from this JSON array using XPath.

I tried few ways but didn't succeed.   Any idea?

```
{  
       "legend_size":1,
       "data":{  
          "series":[  
             "2016-06-01",
             "2016-07-01"
          ],
          "values":{  
             "Download":{  
                "2016-07-01":143,
                "2016-06-01":2124
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath (traditionally, prior to v3.1, which is not widely supported) is defined over XML, not JSON.

Alternatively, consider [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), an "XPath for JSON," which is also [supported by Dojo Toolkit](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/03/17/jsonpath-support/).

In JSONPath, `2124` could be accessed as `$.data.values.Download.2016-06-01`

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 3.1, it would be

```
let $j := parse-json($input)
return array:for-each($j?data?series,
   function($date) {$j?data?values($date)})
```

XPath 3.1 is the first version of XPath to support JSON as well as XML.